# Can a x509Certificate still be used for decryption after the NotAfter has elapsed?

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have an SSL certificate that is about to expire.
I have used the same CSR to apply for a renewal and have been provided with a new SSL certificate containing the public key.
I noticed that I can still use my old x509certificate to decrypt data encrypted with the new certificate.

Do I need to replace the certificate I used to create the x509certificate that is used to do the decryption? Would it stop working after the `NotAfter` has elapsed?

If I do need to, how do I obtain the certificate with the private key and the new expiration date? Am I able to generate it using any .NET Core libraries?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that I can still use my old x509certificate to decrypt data encrypted with the new certificate.

what kind of data you encrypt and decrypt using SSL certificate? SSL certificate MUST NOT be used in any other scenario except protecting SSL/TLS connections. Data encryption certificate is a different entity/certificate.

> Would it stop working after the NotAfter has elapsed?

no. Decryption does not validate certificate or its fields at all. Decryption works as long as you have access to private key.

> If I do need to, how do I obtain the certificate with the private key and the new expiration date?

contact your PKI admins or certification authority. Never ever use self-signed certificates in production.